# Drupal cannot find user login page

Tags: users

i was having some problems with my settings.php file.  I fixed this but now my user page isn't found and I cannot login.  Anyone know how to fix this?  Thanks!

Authorize.php loads but obviously i cannot get in

nevermind i think it's an issue with hostgator

Comment: It is helpful to let us know what you have tried; basics: `website.dev/user/login` and `website.dev/?q=user/login` not working?

Comment: okay when i found a login screen and when I try to login i get a 404 error

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this help others. 
If you are using drupal with a temporary URL on a hostgator server, follow this link 
http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/drupal/using-drupal-with-a-temporary-url

Answer (score 2):

What kind of problems exactly?

If you changed something in settings.php:

- make a backup of settings.php
- put back a default one with your DB details
- try to login again

If you can't, post here the errors you are getting.

Comment: i am not sure.  hostgator actually fixed my settings.php file.  and i do not want to touch it.  my index page loads now but no other pages load.

Comment: i get a 404 page

Comment: sorry, okay, authorize.php loads but obviously i cannot get in

Comment: Post the settings.php file here. Cut out the database access and the URL but leave everything else.